# CONVERT: GIT SHELL to GIT BATCH script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, ubuntu

I need some help how can I edited this code from a shell script to batch script, since i want to run it also in windows.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 commit_limit='4'
 log=`git show HEAD~$commit_limit --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch`

 echo $log > .git/info/grafts
 git filter-branch -f -- --all
 rm .git/info/grafts
 git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master  
 git reflog expire --expire=now --all
 git gc --force --prune=now --aggressive
 git push --force origin $branch
```

i tried this but it give me an output **"H"** instead of **"9b027aaccb996ae4895e4dfb428c5e6e24870e68"**

```
SET commit_limit=4
git show HEAD~%commit_limit% --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch
pause
```

Comment: i tried this but it give me an output "H"

@echo off

SET commit_limit=4

git show HEAD~%commit_limit% --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch

pause

Comment: i tried this but it give me an output "H" instead of "9b027aaccb996ae4895e4dfb428c5e6e24870e68" >>> 

SET commit_limit=4

git show HEAD~%commit_limit% --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch

pause

Comment: Batch File does not work but works in cmd with this command:

git show HEAD~4 --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch

Comment: Try `"%%H"` in batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In variable you have to escape percent sign (`%`) with double percent
  (`%%`).
- replaced `/` with `\` in `del` command.
- `$branch` is a
  shell variable. I fixed to batch syntax `%branch%`, you have to edit
  this variable.

---

```
@echo off

setlocal
rem edit branch variable
set "branch=branch"

set "commit_limit=4"
set "log=git show HEAD~%%commit_limit%% --pretty=format:"%%H" --no-patch"

%log% > .git\info\grafts

git filter-branch -f -- --all
del .git\info\grafts
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master  
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --force --prune=now --aggressive
git push --force origin %branch%
```

---

Further reading:

- [Converting DOS Batch Files to Shell Scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html)
- http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=batch+escaping+characters